# asp.net jQuery focus causes full postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have a form with dynamically generated textboxes that each have a postback trigger for an OnTextChanged event (auto postback). The textboxes are all placed within an update panel so that a different section of the page updates asynchronously after the user enters in values in the textboxes.

When you enter in a value in one of the textboxes, then click into one of the other textboxes (to enter another value) the new textbox focus is lost after the OnTextChanged event. To combat that I am setting the new textbox id to a client side session variable so that when the OnTextChanged event is done (on the server side) I can read the client side session variable and set the appropriate  textbox focus.

The issue I'm having is that when I try to set the focus of the new textbox via jQuery, the page will issue a full postback (the screen flashes) almost randomly (every 2 or 3 textbox entries). If I comment out only the line of code that sets the focus, the page doesn't do a full postback. The worst part is if I set a break point in the browser before the jQuery focus event it still does the full page postback before the breakpoint is even hit, it only gets there after the full postback. How does this even happen?

Edit:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbMonth" CssClass="LHSTextBox" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" OnTextChanged="SubCat_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"</asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:ListView>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

JavaScript that gets newly selected textbox ID:

```
$(".LHSTextBox").focusin(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem('newFocus', this.id);
});
```

C# OnTextChanged function:

```
protected void SubCat_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "setFocusOnIdKey", "setFocusOnId()", true);
}
```

JavaScript function I call after the OnTextChanged server side function:

```
function setFocusOnId() {
    var newFocus = sessionStorage.getItem('newFocus');
    if (newFocus !== null) {
        $('#' + newFocus).focus(); 
        //if I comment out this line, the page doesn't do a full postback, but if I leave it in, it will, even before this is hit
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you may have some other handlers or code applied.  Can you give a sample of the inputs causing the problems, including the server-generated attributes?  E.g., what shows in the Chrome 'Elements' tab, since that should update when other scripts run.

Comment: @ps2goat just updated with more code